# How to deal wioth two or more double inverted commas in same string?

Tags: php

I have a php code which takes an input value from database and stores it in a variable, the input is a fixed sms template which cannot be changed.

So I have to store that in a variable to send sms to users.

```
 $sql = "Select * from `test` where `flag` = '0'";
 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

   if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
      // output data of each row
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

$n = $row['number'];
$m = $row['user'];
$p = $row['pass'];

$request =""; //initialise the request variable
$param['method']= "sendMessage";
$param['send_to'] = "$n";
$param['msg'] = "Dear Customer, Delighted to inform you about "MYZICOM app" India's first service app in security industry . Download now and get 24*7 Service and bills management assistance for your ZICOM MYCS security solutions & services with many more benefits. Your Unique Username: $m & Password: $p. For any queries /assistance pls call 1800-270-4567 (Currently available only for Android users)";    
   $param['userid'] = "XXXX";
   $param['password'] = "XXXX";
    $param['v'] = "1.1";
   $param['msg_type'] = "TEXT"; //Can be "FLASHâ€/"UNICODE_TEXT"  /â€BINARYâ€
  $param['auth_scheme'] = "PLAIN";
//Have to URL encode the values
    foreach($param as $key=>$val) {
 $request.= $key."=".urlencode($val);
 //we have to urlencode the values
 $request.= "&";
//append the ampersand (&) sign after eachparameter/value pair
   }
    $request = substr($request, 0, strlen($request)-1);
 //remove final (&) sign from the request
  $url ="http://enterprise.smsgupshup.com/GatewayAPI/rest?".$request;
$ch = curl_init($url);
// $data = $ch;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

So the problem is there is a fixed single and double inverted comma in my text message and i have to store that in a variable.
How to solve it ?

Comment: Try a \ before the "

Comment: The line that starts with `$param['msg'] = ` is invalid PHP code. Even the syntax highlighter of SO knows this. Read about [PHP strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

Comment: You could also store that SMS template through heredoc syntax.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in my comment, escape the " with a backslash \ i.e.

```
$param['msg'] = "Dear Customer, Delighted to inform you about \"MYZICOM app\" India's first service app in security industry . Download now and get 24*7 Service and bills management assistance for your ZICOM MYCS security solutions & services with many more benefits. Your Unique Username: $m & Password: $p. For any queries /assistance pls call 1800-270-4567 (Currently available only for Android users)";
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply can escape the double inverted comma by using a '\'

```
$str = "test \"foobar\" test";
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$param['msg'] = addslashes("Dear Customer, Delighted to inform you about "MYZICOM app" India's first service app in security industry . Download now and get 24*7 Service and bills management assistance for your ZICOM MYCS security solutions & services with many more benefits. Your Unique Username: $m & Password: $p. For any queries /assistance pls call 1800-270-4567 (Currently available only for Android users)");
```

Comment: This has exactly the same problem as the poster's original code.

Comment: *Well do one thing make you string like .............  *  $param['msg']="Dear Customer, Delighted to inform you about \"MYZICOM app\" India's first service app in security industry . Download now and get 24*7 Service and bills management assistance for your ZICOM MYCS security solutions & services with many more benefits. Your Unique Username: $m & Password: $p. For any queries /assistance pls call 1800-270-4567 (Currently available only for Android users)"